# Makefile searching for a library file

Tags: linux, makefile, lapack

In an auxiliary make file (named `arch.make`) which contains some libraries, I have wrote

```
FFLAGS=-g -O2
FPPFLAGS= -DMPI -DFC_HAVE_FLUSH -DFC_HAVE_ABORT
LDFLAGS=-L/export/apps/computer/lapack-3.2

LAPACK_LIBS=-llapack_LINUX
LIBS=$(LAPACK_LIBS)
```

Then, the Makefile contains

```
siesta: check-siesta what version $(MPI_INTERFACE) $(FDF) $(WXML) $(XMLPARSER) \
            $(COMP_LIBS) $(ALL_OBJS)
    $(FC) -o siesta \
           $(LDFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJS) $(FDF) $(WXML) $(XMLPARSER) $(MPI_INTERFACE)\
           $(COMP_LIBS) $(FoX_LIBS) $(LIBS)
```

Other variables are fine. Please note `$(LIBS)` and `$(LDFLAGS)` which are defined in `arch.make`.

That library file really exists according to

```
root@cluster:ObjPar# ls /export/apps/computer/lapack-3.2/lapack_LINUX.a -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18296682 Jul 10 20:50 /export/apps/computer/lapack-3.2/lapack_LINUX.a
```

However, the make process exits with the following error

```
......
dc_lapack.a `FoX/FoX-config --libs --wcml`   -llapack_LINUX -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack_LINUX
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There are many lines before that but I omitted them.

What should I do?

Comment: When you specify `-lxyz`, the linker looks for `libxyz.a` or `libxyz.so`.  When you have `xyz` spelled `lapack_LINUX`, the linker doesn't even try to look for the file you say contains the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker does not find a file called `liblapack_LINUX.a` or `liblapack_LINUX.so`.  You will need to point to the file directly with

```
LAPACK_LIBS=/export/apps/computer/lapack-3.2/lapack_LINUX.a
```

The `LDFLAGS` variable may be removed.

You are likely to have to link the BLAS library in this way as well if the library is not called `libblas.a` or `libblas.so`. The order of linking may also be important. BLAS before LAPACK.

Comment: Yes, I will try BLAS later. Thing I want to know is that why it doesn't search that path which is given by LDFLAGS?

Comment: @mahmood It does, but the library itself has the wrong name. When you use `-lmylib`, the linker looks for `libmylib.a` and `libmylib.so`, not for `mylib.a` nor `mylib.so`.